# What would be a few ideas/concepts from programming that I can have on paper and hang on a wall as art?

Tags: code-snippets

And by that I mean any piece of code, or an idea presented in pseudo code, something which is very important and is almost art now.
I intend to put up a few paintings and work on paper around my office which depict engineering, rather celebrate engineering. I want them to be not so ordinary like e=mc2 or anything too common or geeky, like 42. They be special, they be important and have earned the position of being almost sacred owing to their contribution to their field. So I want a representation of computer programing as well.
I hope I'm not asking this in the wrong community and apologies already if I am. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Consider asking at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Brian - I want to avoid depictions of the trade in literature, so xkcd or dilbert isn't quite making it for me. Thanks for the tip anyway, m sure xkcd can show up somewhere around the office.
@rwong - noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no-one has mentioned this ASCII fork bomb yet:

`:(){ :|:& };:`

It was [presented as art](https://jaromil.dyne.org/journal/forkbomb_art.html) in 2002 by [Jaromil, AKA Denis Roio](https://jaromil.dyne.org).

WARNING: Entered into a terminal, this snippet will spawn new processes at an exponential rate until your computer grinds to a halt and starts shutting down essential processes. You have been warned!

Answer (score 1):

Should fit on a poster:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/

Comment: I did consider Linux but I just don't know what to put up from the entire code base. I have selected the number 0000:7C00 so far. It would be great if you can add any more identifiers. Thanks for pitching in.

Comment: I have got such a poster (A2 format I believe) on some fair with hundreds/thousands of lines printed in a very tiny font. It looked just good from a distance and was interesting to study it for a few seconds.

Comment: Now loads of text in small font is an idea I hadn't thought of. Thinking. Thanking.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the infamous DVD DeCSS code [on a poster](http://www.cafepress.com/+decss_prime_perl_poster,4614920). I'm sure there's more, I just can't think of any at the moment.

Comment: Have to check if it can get me to serve time somewhere, or else its a great add. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLID** (Single responsibility, Open-closed, Liskov substitution, Interface segregation and Dependency inversion) is a mnemonic acronym introduced by Michael Feathers for the "first five principles" named by Robert C. Martin[1][2] in the early 2000s[3] that stands for five basic principles of object-oriented programming and design.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Answer (score 0):

Lisp in Lisp. Decorate as appropriate. Short, sweet, and revolutionary.

http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/paulgraham/jmc.lisp